# Proving for two naturally isomorphic functors, if one is full, then so is the other.

Tags: category-theory, functors, natural-transformations

So we let $S,T : \mathscr{C} \rightarrow \mathscr{D}$ be naturally isomorphic functors. We seek to show that if $S$ is a full functor, then so is $T$.

As given, we have a natural isomorphism $\tau : S \rightarrow T$, which also means that each component of it $\tau_A : S(A) \rightarrow T(A)$ is invertible.

From here, though, I get pretty lost and have no clue where to go. I'm not even 100% sure how to best show surjectivity in the context of category theory. I feel like that I would have to use the inverse of the natural transformation, $\tau^{-1}$, and that surjectivity implies right-cancellativity, i.e. $S$'s arrow function has a right-sided inverse $S^{-1}$. But I'm honestly just lost.

Does anyone have a potential nudge in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a natural isomorphism $η : F →̣ G$ means we have
$η ∘ F f  = G f ∘ η$ for all $f$, moreover the $\eta$ are invertible.

Now the required proof progresses as follows :-)

$$\def\room{\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad}$$

\begin{align*}
   & F \; \mathsf{full} 
\\ ≡\; & \color{green}{\{\text{ Definition of full }\}} \\
  & ∀x,y • ∀ f′ : F x → F    •  ∃ f : x → y \;• \room F f = f′
\\ ≡\; & \color{green}{\{\text{ Using natural isomorphism }\}} \\
 & ∀x,y •  ∀ f′ : F x → F    •  ∃ f : x → y \;•\room η⁻¹ ∘ G f ∘ η = f′
\\ ≡\; & \color{green}{\{\text{ Using natural isomorphism  }\}} \\
 & ∀x,y •  ∀ f′ : F x → F    •  ∃ f : x → y \;•\room G f = η ∘ f′ ∘ η⁻¹
\\ ≡\; & \color{green}{\{\text{ Local declaration ---aka `one point rule' }\}} \\
 & ∀x,y •  ∀ f′ : F x → F    •  ∀ f″ : G x → G y • ∃ f : x → y \;• \room G f = f″   \quad ∧ \quad  f″ = η ∘ f′ ∘ η⁻¹
\\ ⇒\; & \color{green}{\{\text{ Weaken by discarding a conjunct }\}} \\
& ∀ x,y •  ∀ f′ : F x → F y  •  ∀ f″ : G x → G y • ∃ f : x → y \;• \qquad G f = f″
\\ ⇒ \; & \color{green}{\{\text{ Remove superfluous $∀ f′$ }\}} \\
& ∀ x,y •  ∀ f″ : G x → G y  • ∃ f : x → y \;•\room G f = f″
\\ ≡ \; & \color{green}{\{\text{ Definition of full }\}} \\
& G \; \mathsf{full} & &
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You have to relate the maps $\hom(c,d)\to \hom(S(c),S(d))$ and $\hom(c,d)\to\hom(T(c),T(d))$ for any $c,d\in\mathscr C$. This can be done by using the natural isomorphism in order to produce a bijective map $\hom(S(c),S(d))\to \hom(T(c), T(d))$ that commutes with the above maps.