# Showing when two functors are naturally isomorphic, if one is faithful, then the other also is.

Tags: category-theory, functors, natural-transformations

Supposing we have a natural isomorphism $\tau : S \rightarrow T$ between functors $S,T : \mathscr{C} \rightarrow \mathscr{D}$, how exactly do we show that if $S$ is faithful, then so is $T$?

If $S$ is faithful, then it is injective on the hom-sets, i.e. if $f = g$, then $S(f) = S(g)$. I also know that the components of the natural transformation form a commutative square defined by $\tau \circ S(f) = T(f) \circ \tau$, and that the ultimate implication I want to show is (*probably along the lines of?*)

$$f = g \;\;\; \Rightarrow \;\;\; S(f)=S(g) \;\;\; \Rightarrow \;\;\; T(f)=T(g)$$

(with the first implication being given as stated by $S$ being faithful).

I've tried playing with around with some of the compositions but the closest I've gotten would be $T(\tau(f)) = T(\tau(g))$ (which came from $S(f)=S(g)$, composing on the right by $\tau$ which is injective, and then applying the definition from the commuting square) which I don't think is sufficient. Really, I'm starting to think that the composition idea isn't going to work, and that proving such things from a categorical perspective is a little bit more nuanced than we'd see in, say, a set theory class, and maybe I'm just not thinking "categorically", so to speak? I'm not sure.

Anyhow, sorry for the dumb question, but any ideas?

Comment: Your implication regarding $S$ being faithful actually says that $S$ is a function.

Comment: Yeah you’re running implications the wrong way.

Comment: @KevinCarlson (For the record I get your answer proper, I'm just curious.) Since $S$ being faithful means $S$'s arrow function is injective ... I'm not sure what the issue is exactly? In this context is $S$ not a function, because - again, in this context - we're looking at the behavior of $S$'s arrow function?

Comment: @Randall Thanks, I got the arrows mixed up after all. I think I usually approached it from the "contrapositive" view ($x\neq y \Rightarrow f(x) \neq f(y)$) looking back at my older coursework and I guess I got the wires crossed since then.

Comment: The proof is the same as the one given here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3004250/proving-for-two-naturally-isomorphic-functors-if-one-is-full-then-so-is-the-ot/3004388#3004388, except the compositions are the other way around -- duality!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that $T(f)=\tau_y S(f)\tau_x^{-1}$. So if $T(f)=T(g)$, then the same thing is true for $S(f)$ and $S(g)$, up to composition with some isomorphisms. Cancel the isomorphisms!